# Select those records in random where sum of marks is less than 10

Tags: php, mysql

I am having following table.

```
Question  Marks
----------------
Qns 1      1
Qns 2      2
Qns 3      2
Qns 4      1
Qns 5      1
Qns 6      1
```

Now I need to select question in random where `SUM(marks) = 4`

Expected Results can be

```
1, 4, 5, 6
```

OR

```
2, 3
```

OR

```
1, 2, 4
```

and So On..

I want help in writing SQL Query.

Comment: This could end up being a huge result statistically based off of your original data set.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Joseph_J I wanted to fetch the question in random where SUM of marks is less then some number. This is what I want to do.

Comment: Why that criteria?  Can it be done an easier way?  What I mean is that there are potentially so many ways to get something to  sum to 4.  Do I pick four questions or two.  The potential combinations here could be very high and really pointless for just selecting questions.  You need to think of additional parameters to select your questions.

Comment: Also, you have said what you want, but you have not posted any code to show us what you have tried.  Please post some code in your post.

Comment: @Joseph_J What if I go with atleast one '2' marks should be there. Does this sounds good?

Comment: What if I have an array of just 100 question and 50 of them have 2's and the others are 1's.  To list all possible combinations of questions that sum to 4 is incredibly high. And on many of the possible combinations your range of questions will be from 2 to 4.

Comment: @Joseph_J What I am trying to do is, I'm creating Online Test in which I will store all the Question in the DB and when I will create Test I will mention Total Marks lets say (50), So It will automatically create Test of 50 Marks by selecting Question randomly

Comment: I understand that, but to be random you have to generate a list of all possible sums to 4 then pick a set of questions from that.

Comment: How many questions we talking about in your DB?

Comment: @Joseph_J So can you say any other alternative for doing the same?

Comment: How many questions in your DB?

Comment: @Joseph_J It may be 100 or even more. It's kind of a Question Bank and from there we will select Question.

Comment: @joseph_j at 100, it's not incredibly high, so quite manageable in sql. But at 10000, it starts to be less wieldy.

Comment: What will be the Query to solve that, can you please tell

Comment: @Strawberry  You are correct.  I was just trying to illustrate the point that he was likely going to generate way more possible combinations of question sets than his original sample size.  I was also trying to point out that there was no way to guarantee how many questions would be returned.  But thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will concede that I do not know how to do this with a query.  But if you do a query that selects all of your questions that you want to sample then here is a PHP solution:

This will sample a random set of desired amount of questions from the sample pool of questions.

It will then sum the values of the randomly selected question set to see if it adds up to your desired "mark" total.

This will be done inside of a while loop.  If the sum does not add up to the desire "mark" total then it will select a new set of random questions from the question pool and try again.  It will do this until the condition is met.

So your risk here is that you enter in parameters that can not be met or are very large.  If this happens the script will run till it times out.

If your sample set is fairly small this should work most the time fairly reliably, but if it's large or there is not a set of questions that can add up to your "mark" total this will not work.

Give it a try:

```
$questions = array(

'1' => 1,
'2' => 2,
'3' => 2,
'4' => 1,
'5' => 1,
'6' => 1

);


function getQuestions($questions, $numberQuestions, $markTotal){

  do{

  $sample = array_rand($questions, $numberQuestions);

  $sum = 0;
  foreach($sample as $key=>$value){

    $sum += $questions[$value];

  }

  }while($sum != $markTotal);

  return $sample;

}


$numberQuestions = 3;
$markTotal = 4;

$results = getQuestions($questions, $numberQuestions, $markTotal);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';

//Outputs
Array
(
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

This will output an array that holds the key values that corresponds to the questions that were selected from your pool of questions.

So I did some basic bench marking and here are some simple observations to help you along:

If you want a test with a lot of questions it will take longer to find a set of questions that add up to you desired mark value.  The fewer test questions the easier it is to find a set of values that add up to your total mark value.

Your range of mark values will make a big difference as well.  The smaller the mark value per question means it's easier to find a series of mark values to add up to your particular total mark score.

If your total mark score is too high relative to the amount of questions you want you may never reach the total mark score.

Having a high amount of questions in your sample question pool seems to have a small effect on time relative to the range of scores per question and how many question you need for you test.

Having a sample question pool of 100 questions, all of which have a score between 0-20 and asking for 10 questions for a total mark score of 50 worked very well.  However, increasing the amount of questions to 20 in the same scenario was very costly.

I found a relationship between the range of scores per question and the number of desired questions per test that seemed to work very well.

If you follow this rule I would expect that you would be able to run this function reliably with minimal cost.

**question pool size = 100**

**score range = 0-20**

**number of desired test questions = 20**

(Average max score range(don't count outliers) **X** # of desired test questions)/2 **=** the mark total you should use.

(20 x 20)/2 = 200 <- Good mark score value.

Of course this is a guideline, I'm sure you could play around and get some results you like.  I would first try playing around by increasing the denominator from 2 to 3 ect... until it fails.  BY increasing the size of the denominator you are saying I want each question to generally consist of lower value scores. The larger the denominator the slower it will be on average and if you go to low it slows down as well.

Examples:

(20 x 20)/1.5 = 266 <- This will look for higher value question scores. Still pretty fast. Values < 1.5 really start to slow it down.

(20 x 20)/2 = 200 <- This will generally get questions across the entire range of values. - Very fast!

(20 x 20)/3 = 133 <- Still a reliable mark score value.  This will generally find more of the lower value questions. - Still fairly fast.

(20 x 20)/4 = 100 <- This will look for primarily lower value questions. - As the denominator grows bigger from here it will become more costly and slower.

The size of your question pool does play a factor.  If something starts to run slow add more questions to your question pool and see if that helps you.

So if you wanted a mark score of 50 you could see how your limited on how many questions you can have on your test in relation to the range of scores for the questions.

Just some food for thought.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for giving this idea. I will try to implement this.